# Import CSV file with different number of columns into MySQL table

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I have a CSV file with the following format:

```
"movieId";"Genre" 
"tt0111161";"Drama","Crime" 
"tt0468569";"Action","Drama","Crime"
"tt0021331"
"tt1853728";"Western"
```

I would like to import this CSV file into Mysql table "movieGenres" which has 2 columns "movieId" and "Genre". So, I need the results in a table as below:

```
 movieId   | Genre 
 -------------------------------
 tt0111161 | Drama,Crime 
 tt0468569 | Action,Drama,Crime
 tt0021331 |
 tt1853728 | Western
```

The problem is when I try to import, it stop after a while with showing the error : "Invalid number of columns at line ...". 
This is because when it reach to the line where there is only one column, it stops (like the 3rd movie in my example, because there are some movies wit NO genres).

I really don't know how I can fix this problem. Could someone please help me?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value of the second column before inserting it into the database like this example:

```
#table: example

col-1 col-2 col-3 col-4

LOAD DATA INFILE ‘path/to/example.csv’ INTO TABLE example FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘,’ LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\n’ IGNORE 1 LINES (col-1,col-2,col-3, @var1) SET col-4 = CASE WHEN @var1 IS NOT NULL 
       THEN @var1
       ELSE NULL
END
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. just one question: why did you write `SET col-4 = CASE WHEN @var1 IS NOT NULL`? I mean when @var1 IS NULL (empty), I need to set it to something.. Am I misunderstood?

Comment: var1 is actually 4th column value in csv, so we are checking if it is empty then return null otherwise return the actual value which we are then putting in the table col-4. Hope it is clear now

Comment: thanks a lot. Is there a similar way in phpMyAdmin to do the same thing? Actually, unfortunately I am working on a DB which is on a remote server and I only have access to the link to phpmyadmin..

Comment: the query will work in any sql client including phpmyadmin , only thing you need to make sure is that the file ‘path/to/example.csv’ is present and you have access to import it